# Network Lobby manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm developing a multiplayer online application with unity3D, and I'm using `networkLobbyManager`, I managed to create a match and allow the players to join the match by running `matchMaker.JoinMatch` so I have all the players in **"Lobby Scene"** but I did not understand how we can join them in "play scene".
(I have found that we can move to play scene only if all players are ready, but I do not understand how I can put them all ready). my code :

```
public InputField impF;
public InputField impF1;
public Dropdown d;
List<MatchInfoSnapshot> m;
MatchInfoSnapshot ma;
public int n = 1;

// Use this for initialization
public void enableMatch()
{
    Debug.Log("@ MMStart ");
    this.StartMatchMaker();
}

public override void OnStartHost()
{
    base.OnStartHost();
    Debug.Log("the game has created");
}

public void crereMatch()
{
    string nom = impF.text;
    Debug.Log(nom);
    MMCreateMateches(nom);
    n = 2;
}

public void findMtches()
{
    MMListMateches();
}

public void joinMatch()
{
    Debug.Log(d.options[d.value].text);
    foreach (var match in this.matches)
    {
        Debug.Log("dans la boucle des matches");
        Debug.Log(match.name);
        if ((d.options[d.value].text).Equals(match.name))
        {
            //on récupere 
            ma = match;
            Debug.Log("dans le if " + ma.name);
            break;
        }
    }
    // this.f
    m = this.matches;
    ma = m.Find(x => (x.name).Equals(ma.name));
    Debug.Log("apres recuperation de la liste" + ma.name);
    MMjoinMateches(ma);
}

void MMListMateches()
{
    Debug.Log("@ MMListMateches ");
    this.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 20, "", true, 0, 0, OnMatchList);
}

public override void OnMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, List<MatchInfoSnapshot> matchList)
{
    Debug.Log("@ OnMatchList ");
    base.OnMatchList(success, extendedInfo, matchList);
    if (!success)
    {
        Debug.Log("liste failed " + extendedInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {  //les matches en cours > 0 ms on doit le joiner 
            Debug.Log("succesfully listed match 1 er match :" + matchList[0]);
            Debug.Log(matchList[0].name);
            foreach (var match in this.matches)
            {
                Debug.Log("dans la boucle");
                Debug.Log(match.name);
                Debug.Log(" wééééééééééééééééééé ");
            }
            d.ClearOptions();
            foreach (var match in this.matches)
            {
                Debug.Log(match.name);
                // impF1.text = match.name;
                List<string> m_DropOptions = new List<string> { match.name };

                d.AddOptions(m_DropOptions);
            }
            //   MMjoinMateches(matchList[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("no mateches");
            // MMCreateMateches();
        }
    }
}

void MMjoinMateches(MatchInfoSnapshot firstMatch)
{
    Debug.Log("@ MMjoinMateches ");
    this.matchMaker.JoinMatch(firstMatch.networkId, "", "", "", 0, 0, OnMatchJoined);
}

public override void OnMatchJoined(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    Debug.Log("@ OnMatchJoined ");
    base.OnMatchJoined(success, extendedInfo, matchInfo);
    if (!success)
    {
        Debug.Log("failed to join match " + extendedInfo);
        impF1.text = "failed";
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("succesfuly joined match " + matchInfo.networkId);
        impF1.text = "succes";
        this.StartClient(matchInfo);
    }
}

void MMCreateMateches(string nom)
{
    Debug.Log("@ MMCreateMateches ");
    Debug.Log(nom);
    this.matchMaker.CreateMatch(nom, 15, true, "", "", "", 0, 0, OnMatchCreate);
}

public override void OnMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    Debug.Log("@ OnMatchCreate ");
    base.OnMatchCreate(success, extendedInfo, matchInfo);
    if (!success)
    {

        Debug.Log("failed to create match " + extendedInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("succesfuly created match " + matchInfo.networkId);
        OnStartHost();
    }
}

public override void OnLobbyServerPlayersReady()
{
    base.OnLobbyServerPlayersReady();
}
```

Comment: If this is a code question, please post some code so we can see the problem. If this is not a code question, it probably doesn't belong in Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes it's code  qs, here is my code:

Comment: Thanks for the code! Could you please show where the problem is?

Comment: @kismert I don't think he/she is having a problem with the code itself, just needs some directions for approaching the problem, which is joining the players together in the actual play scene after they meet in the lobby.

Comment: @captainCrazy    yes I can not access a play scene, I do not know how to change the status of the client and make it a ready

Comment: sincerely i am beginner with unity if you can give me more details on the functioning of the network lobby manager

Comment: @captainCrazy as long as the domain experts have enough information to answer M.feriel's question, I am happy

Comment: @M.feriel Well, still no answer. Maybe you need to make a smaller code example that shows only the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Watch this tutorial by Holistic 3D on how to setup `Unity Network Lobb`y (Free in the Asset Store). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jklWlm5v21k

In the settings, you determine `Max Players` needed to enter a room. You can set it to '1' so anyone can enter at anytime.

Change Max Players from 4 to 1 [See Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg91C.png)